# When I run the image on my PC for Docker, I got below error all the time

Tags: compiler-errors, docker

This is my first time to learn the Docker, I follow the steps as Docker's instructions mentioned, but wen I run below command in the `Boot2Docker Start:
$ docker run hello-world`, I got below error response:

```
An error occurred trying to connect: 
Post https://192.168.59.103:2376/v1.19/containers/create: Service Unavailable
```

Comment: What version of VirtualBox do you have?

Comment: Hi Vonc, the version is:4.3.28 r 100309.

Comment: As in http://stackoverflow.com/a/30466305/6309, can you try `boot2docker start`, `boot2docker shellinit`, and `boot2docker ssh`?

Comment: It is so cool. I got below response now:Docker version 1.7.0, build 0baf609
docker@boot2docker:~$ docker run hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
Pulling repository hello-world
Get https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/hello-world/images: dial tcp
 52.5.165.233:443: connection timed out. So it means the network issue or still has any other problems?

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: I checked my LAN setting on browser, and make sure that use proxy check box is unchecked, and run again, still show time out:-(.

Comment: Do you have an HTTP_PROXY environment variable defined (in your docker session)?

Comment: Try `unset http_proxy=`, and `docker restart`

Comment: Vonc, I find I have one https_proxy environment variable defined, I see it in  my system variable and delete it now, the result still as before(time out).

Comment: VonC,I tried your way, however, still shows timeout. anyway, I agree with you, I think this issue should be network issue, so mark my question get answer and thanks a lot!

Comment: Let me know if you find the root cause of that timeout issue

Comment: docker run -it -p 80:80 fe65a2781dae /bin/bash, use this command, it can resolve my issue.

Comment: Great: I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility. What image is represented by `fe65a2781dae`?

Comment: fe65a2781dae tell the image id that when Docker running use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to reset/restart boot2docker:

```
boot2docker start
boot2docker shellinit
boot2docker ssh
```

After that, any connection issue could be due to a proxy.

The [OP Ray](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5200383/ray) [resolves the timeout issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31870390/when-i-run-the-image-on-my-pc-for-docker-i-got-below-error-all-the-time?noredirect=1#comment51715983_31870390) by opening a bash in a container:

```
 docker run -it -p 80:80 fe65a2781dae /bin/bash,
```